# Dynamic ng-model name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with inputs that are generated dynamically.
How can I get their values?

```
<p ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedTemplate.attributes.Params.attributes">
    {{key}} : <tr><input ng-model="params[key]" type="text" placeholder="{{value}}" >
</p>

//attributes are like this
"attributes": {
    "End Date": "java.sql.Timestamp",
    "Containers": "java.lang.Object",
    "Begin Date": "java.sql.Timestamp"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi please make demo, so i can help

Comment: Please provide mode code, preferably as a plunker (https://plnkr.co/) to assist.

Comment: You should make the demo.

Comment: thanks a lost! i forgot to declare $scope.params = {} in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `$scope.params = {}` in your controller.
and after that you can access the values by :
`$scope.params['End Date']`, `$scope.params['Containers']`, `$scope.params['Begin Date']`

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that params will be created inside ng-repeat scope. So, you will need to declare it inside controller initialization :

```
$scope.params = [];
```

then, to loop through your variables, you can do the following inside your controller:

```
for (var key in attributes) {
  if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert($scope.params[key]);
  }
}
```

By the way, params is a reserved keyword. Using it can fail in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo for you: [Here](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/mEbLWo)

I create simple example with ng-model name, follow it and apply for your case.

HTML:

```
<p ng-repeat="(key, value) in attributes track by $index">
   <input ng-model="params[key]" type="text" placeholder="{{value}}" >
</p>

<p>{{params}}</p>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.attributes = {
    "End Date": "java.sql.Timestamp",
    "Containers": "java.lang.Object",
    "Begin Date": "java.sql.Timestamp"
 };

 // You should create params variable.
 $scope.params = {};
```